# Python subprocess Popen with a seekable pipe?

Tags: python, subprocess

I am calling a binary from Python with `subprocess.Popen`. I'm passing `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` so I can pipe the output straight into my Python program and telling the program to send its output to `STDOUT` rather than a file. It looks like the binary I'm calling wants to be able to seek on the output file. It's not possible to seek on this pipe and I'm getting an error.

I could create a temporary file in Python and tell the binary to write to that, then read it, but that would slow things down quite a lot.

Any suggestions for passing some kind of in-memory buffer to the binary so the program can write and seek, but I can get at it once it is flushed?

Comment: That's a pretty tough situation - well behaved unix tools shouldn't seek on stdout. I think a temporary file is your only real option.

Comment: Well the program expects a real file argument but accepts "-" as meaning 'use stdout'. It doesn't play nicely with it, but it does at least try (writes half the file before bombing)!

Comment: @Joe - See my edit in the answer for a second tentative hack!

Comment: Do you know what the program is trying to accomplish by seeking? What program is this? It doesn't matter how you redirect stdout within your Python script, since from the point of view of the spawned program, stdout and its interface will remain unchanged.

Comment: It's a file format converter. It's seeking back to fix-up some block headers, I think. I've fixed the problem another way.

Comment: @Joe you said you solved the problem but you didn't answer your question. Can you come back and submit an answer to your own question and accept it?

Comment: Sorry @AlexVidal, this was nearly 3 years ago! I think I just used a temporary real file.