# How to create a Filehandle in memory and pass to an external command in Python

Tags: python, file

I have a small in-house Python script for Linux that creates a /home/user/environ_script.sh file in the users $HOME directory and then loads the environment in their shell via

`subprocess.call('bash --rcfile  /home/user/environ_script.sh')`

Script works fine yet I was wondering if this can be done without writing to disk at all? Similar to how bash's 
process substitution command

`foo <(command)`

provides "command" output as the input for foo via a temporary filehandle /dev/fdx since foo expects a Filehandle.

Comment: check out the [tempfile](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html) module ?

Comment: hmm.. reading tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile()..

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8467588/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you're looking is a [named pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe), that is, a mechanism for interprocess communication that can be used as a file, but that isn't written to disk:

```
import subprocess
import os

fifo_name = 'my-bash.rc'
os.mkfifo(fifo_name)

try:
    process = subprocess.Popen(['bash', '--rcfile', fifo_name])
    with open(fifo_name, 'w') as f:
        f.write('echo "This is my-bash.rc"')
    process.wait()
finally:
    os.remove(fifo_name)
```

In the example above a named pipe is created and passed to the subprocess to open it for reading. In the python side, the same pipe is opened for writing, some contents is written and the pipe is closed. The subprocess receives the contents of the pipe and continues as if that contents was read from a real file.

Comment: This would work if "bash --rcfile" could read from stdin but it only accepts a file handle.

Comment: I think I now understand your requirements and I've updated my response accordingly.

Comment: ah great, forgot about named pipes.. this solution works rather nicely, thanks!